# Apache always get 403 permisson after changing DocumentRoot

Tags: apache, freebsd

I'm just a newbie for Apache. I just installed apache 2.2 on the FreeBSD box at my home office. The instruction on FreeBSD documentation is that I can change the DocumentRoot directive in order to use the customized directory data. Therefore, I replaced...

```
/usr/local/www/apache22/data
```

with

```
/usr/home/some_user/public_html
```

but something is not right. There's index.html file inside the directory, but it seems that apache could not read the directory/file.

```
Forbidden
You don't have permission to access / on this server.
```

The permission of

```
public_html
```

is

```
drwxr-xr-x
```

I wonder what could be wrong here. Also, in my case, I am not going to host more than one website for this FreeBSD box, so I didn't look at using VirtualHost at all. Is this a good practice just to change the DirectoryRoot directive?

Comment: What's in the apache error log? It's usually quite verbose on that. It's also possible that you need to give ``o+r`` on your home directory.

Comment: Try and `su` to the user who owns the httpd processes (usually `apache`) - can you `cat /usr/home/some_user/public_html/index.html`?

Comment: @Jonas Checked the error log and it said...
`client denied by server configuration: /usr/home/webmaster/public_html/`

Comment: @f_puras There's nothing in that file except for just "hello world".

Comment: That's fine. I was only wondering if Apache is actually permitted to read the file. So the problem must be elsewhere...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Somewhere in the apache config is a line like:

```
# This should be changed to whatever you set DocumentRoot to.
#
<Directory "/usr/local/www/apache22/data">
```

You must change this path too, to make it work. This directive contains for example:

```
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
```

Which give initial user access to the directory.

Comment: Thanks so much! This works perfectly. I thought that configuring <DocumentRoot> was enough for moving the data directory. Apparently, I need to check <Directory> as well.

Answer (score 0):

one possibility that comes to mind is SELinux blocking web process from accessing that folder. If this is the case, you would see it in selinux log. You would have to check the context for your original web root with:

```
ls -Zl
```

and then apply it to your new web folder:

```
chcon whatevercontextyousaw public_html
```

Or, instead, if its not a production server that requires security (like a development machine behind a firewall), you might want to just turn selinux off.

Just one idea. Could be a number of other things.

Comment: Does FreeBSD actually have SELinux?

Comment: well, havent used freebsd for quite a while, being a fedora user myself. tho, since it comes from kernel, I'd think it would.

Comment: @Tungcay

I just checked the context of the original webroot and got...

    drwxr-xr-x  6 root  wheel  - 1024 Aug 27 16:24 data

and this is the public_html

    drwxr-xr-x  6 webmaster  webmaster  - 1024 Aug 27 16:27 public_html

I do not see any differences here...

Comment: a bit late, but, your output shows 'ls -l', not 'ls -lZ'. Note the 'Z'. The -Z parameter gives you selinux context.